# Django can't find can't find packages in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, virtualenv, django-nonrel

I'm trying to set up a virtualenv for local development using Google App Engine and django-nonrel. I'm only trying to run the test app provided by django-nonrel for now.

The first time I tried, I got `python manage.py runserver` to work, but as soon as I tried to fetch a page from `localhost:8080`, it errored out on me, saying it couldn't find the `pdb` module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2755, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2643, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 682, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1717, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1619, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_py27_handler(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1425, in ExecutePy27Handler
    import pdb
ImportError: No module named pdb
```

I tried copying modules from my main Python installation, and I also tried creating a new virtualenv which had access to site-packages. Both approaches worked up to a point - `python manage.py runserver` ended up not being able to find `urllib`.

On the other hand, `python manage.py shell` and then e.g. `import pdb` or `import urrlib` (or any other standard library, for that matter) work fine. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution: don't use `virtualenv` at all, and put the libraries you're going to need (such as `django`) in your project directory. You're going to need that to deploy your app to GAE, anyway.

Comment: I made an effort to log in just to downvote this. Very bad advice.

Comment: @AndrewSledge If you're going to take the time to login to downvote, why not spend some time offering an alternative?